# Iterating raster pairs using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, iteration

I have a problem that must be solved in automatic manner. 
I am using **ArcGIS 10.2**.

I have a raster files that I have to pair and then make the calculation. I have tried to use ModelBuilder but there is not possible to use two iterations. I have made submodel but then it did not pair the layers correctly.

THe calculation on the pairs is simple. Just minus them than the results must be divided by the maximum value from the resulted layer.

I have :

*raster1_yearA, raster1_yearB, raster1_yearC, raster1_yearD

raster2_yearA, raster2_yearB, raster2_yearC, raster2_yearD*

But I have to make pairs lik this:

*raster1_yearA - raster1_yearB

raster1_yearA - raster1_yearC

raster1_yearA - raster1_yearD*

Answer (score 5):

To get started with a Python script you can try code below. ListRasters will sort your rasters by name so if they are named like you say, it should work. Otherwise there are other ways of sorting the list.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
from itertools import izip

folder = r'C:\Test\Rasters' #Or geodatabase. Change to match your data.
arcpy.env.workspace = folder

#Function which return 4 items at a time from list
def fourwise(iterable):
    a = iter(iterable)
    return izip(a, a, a, a)

for a, b, c, d in fourwise(arcpy.ListRasters()):
    outMinus1 = Minus(a,b)
    outMinus2 = Minus(a,c)
    outMinus3 = Minus(a,d)
    #... do something else with outMinuses...
```

Answer (score 3):

To list rasters, you would need to use the [`arcpy.ListRasters()`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listrasters.htm) function. Then you would need to use the [`for`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) loop with the [`Minus` GP tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/minus.htm).